# php mongodb insert unique values only?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

In mysql I can set unique to my table columns so that the user won't insert the same value if that value has already existed,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `screen_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `secret` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `signature` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `visited_on` timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`person_id`,`category_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_name_UNIQUE` (`user_name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `salt_UNIQUE` (`salt`),
  UNIQUE KEY `signature_UNIQUE` (`signature`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

What about in MongoDB? How can I achieve this?

```
$document = array(
    "title" => "Mr",
    "fullname" => "John C",
    "username" => "user1",
    "age" => 20
);
$collection->insert($document);
```

The user with username "user1" is repeated if I run that again. With MySQL, it won't happen and I will get an error. But how can I make Mongo to throw an error if "user1" already exists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your SQL table declaration also declares "unique" index on the "user_name" field. Therefore you want to the same thing in MongoDB, by adding the index:

Either in the shell:

```js
db.collection.createIndex({ "username": 1 },{ "unique": true })
```

Or in PHP code with the same [method](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.createindex.php):

```
$collection->createIndex(
    array( "username", 1 ),
    array( "unique", true )
)
```

Then if you tried to insert something that violated that contraint then you would receive an exception.

If you would prefer to not receive an exception on every insert operation then you can use the ["upsert"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) functionality of MongoDB along with the [**`$setOnInsert`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) update modifier:

```
$document = array(
    "title" => "Mr",
    "fullname" => "John C",
    "username" => "user1",
    "age" => 20
);

$collection->update(
    array("username", $document["username"]),
    array('$setOnInsert',document),
    array("upsert", true)
)
```

That will only make changes when a new document is created and will not modify where one already exists for the queried field(s) value.

Using "upserts" does of course come with the cost of "looking up" the data in the collection, but can also be combined with operations where you do intend to modify the data where the document is matched.

Comment: the record values is not updating if already exists , for example Title Mr after insert and change to Mr123 its not updating , is it possible to update the record other none uniq values if already in db ?

Answer (score 1):

From mongodb doc

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/

Create a Unique Index¶

MongoDB allows you to specify a unique constraint on an index. These constraints prevent applications from inserting documents that have duplicate values for the inserted fields.

MongoDB cannot create a unique index on the specified index field(s) if the collection already contains data that would violate the unique constraint for the index.

Unique Index on a Single Field

To create a unique index, consider the following prototype:

`db.collection.createIndex( { a: 1 }, { unique: true } )`